# SQLAlchemy has no attribute Column

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

Below this is my code i'm learning flask and at this step i'm creating database with flask_sqlachemy. i created an instance of SQLAlchemy that is User, actually i coded like the tutor did but in my case i have this problem, i code this in Pycharm. 'Unresolve attribute refrence Column for class SQLAlchemy' but when i run it there is no error. In the video i saw there is no problem about this. Please help me why pycharm did that!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '2bd147089908273bb6fd4fd4ce75cf7d'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)



class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm just checks if class SQLAlchemy has an attribute "Column" which it does not. You can resolve your PyCham issue by adding `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` before your class, i.e.:

```py
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Also, as soon as you use an [application factory pattern](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/) PyCharm will find the 'Column' attributes.

---

But why are the attributes missing? The answer is in the docstring of the SQLAlchemy object.

> This class also provides access to all the SQLAlchemy functions and classes
> from the :mod:`sqlalchemy` and :mod:`sqlalchemy.orm` modules.  So you can
> declare models like this:

> ```
>    class User(db.Model):
>        username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
>        pw_hash = db.Column(db.String(80))
> ```

> [...] If you use these
> interfaces through :mod:`sqlalchemy` and :mod:`sqlalchemy.orm` directly,
> the default query class will be that of :mod:`sqlalchemy`.

Comment: i understand the first one but the next one im little confuse. can you show me how to use the mod things. thanks anyway

Comment: can you tell me how to use the applcation factory pattern to? please im  a beginner wkwkwk